# Problems with connecting Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

I created a SQL Server on Azure (https://saigkillsbacktrace.database.windows.net) with a Database. Now i'm trying to connect with it via SQL Studio.
Studio tells me, that the host is unknown. But what to do?

Comment: Have you added your IP address to the server's firewall settings?

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Sorry this is my first time with using Azure. Thank you very much